# How can I copy table records unrepeatedly?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains some duplicate redords. I want to make records unique. I created a new table (say, destination) and I specified a unique column in it. How can copy records from table1 (source) such that, if the record inserted in the destination table, it does not insert it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "[select into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)" construct and select insert only distinct rows, like this:

```
insert into table_without_dupes (column0, column1) select distinct column0, column1 from table_with_dupes
```

If you have autoincrement or other columns that makes the rows distinct, you can just leave them out of the insert and select parts of the statement.

#### Edit:

If you want to detect duplicates by a single column, you can use group by:

```
insert into table_without_dupes (column0, column1) select column0, column1 from table_with_dupes group by column0
```

MySQL will allow you to refer non-aggregated columns in select, but remember that the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) says "The server is free to choose any value from each group", if you want to select one specific row of the groups, you might find [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) example useful.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't have any unique value. How can I tell MySQL to distinct based on certain column value ?? I want to copy the whole records, but non duplicated based on the value of a certain column.

Comment: You can use a group by in the select statement on that certain column, the result set will only contain one row per that column's value, but now I'm not sure that i understand your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Generic approach

```
insert into destination(col1,col2)
select DISTINCT col1,col2 from source as s where not exists
(select * from destination as d where d.col1=s.col1)
```

Edited

```
   insert into destination(col1,col2)
   SELECT distinct col1,col2 from source
```

Edited (Assuming col3 is duplicated and you want only one copy of it.)

```
insert into destination(col1,col2,col3,....,colN)
SELECT col1,col2,col3,...,colN from source as s1 inner join
(
select col1,col2,max(col3) as  col3 
from source 
group by col1,col2
) as s2 on t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.col2=t2.col2 and t1.col3=t2.col3
```

Comment: This syntax will not help. My scenario is that I have a new empty table (dest) & I want to insert records from table1 (source) which contains duplicate records. But I want to insert unique values only. Your statement will insert values from (source) if they are not exist in (dest), and since my (dest) is empty, it will insert all records from (source). This will generate error since I created (unique) field in the (dest), and that is what happened.

Comment: I need to copy the whole record. So, I have to not use col1,col2 ?? i.e, use * instead? I have tried this. It does not work.

Comment: To clarify. My (dest) is completely new empty table. I need to insert everything in (source) but without repeating. If a record from (source) inserted in (dest) it should not be inserted again. Your statement insert the same record again. My database generates an error as I created (dest) table with (unique) key that should not be repeated twice.

Comment: I think your statement will serve me, but I need to select the whole distincted record not only col1,col2.

Comment: Ok. If your source table has duplicates you need to eliminate when adding to destination table. Again see my edited post

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into <dest_table_name>
select distinct * from <source_table_name>;
```

Comment: Does not work. It generates error because the new table (dest) has a field (unique) and this field is duplicated in the (source). Your statement will copy all records in (source) that are not exist in (source) which is not what I need. My (dest) is an empty table that I want to fill it with distinct values from (source).